# '[Errno 13] Permission denied' - Jupyter Labs on AWS SageMaker

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker, permission-denied

I'm using a **Jupyter Lab** instance on **AWS SageMaker**.

Kernel: `conda_mxnet_latest_p37`.

`url_lib` contains some false urls, that I exception handle.

```
['15', '259', '26', '58', 'https://imagepool.1und1-drillisch.de/v2/download/nachhaltigkeitsbericht/1&1Drillisch_Sustainability_Report_EN_2018.pdf', 'https://imagepool.1und1-drillisch.de//v2/download/nachhaltigkeitsbericht/2018-04-06_1und1-Drillisch_Sustainability_Report_eng.pdf', '6', 'http://youxin.37.com/uploads/file/1556248045.pdf', '80', 'https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1691941O/2019-sustainability-report.PDF', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ungc-production/attachments/cop_2020/483648/original/GPIC_Sustainability_Report_2020__-_40_Years_of_Sustainable_Success.pdf?1583154650', 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_dnBcfXWjexy9QoWRhOk_3gnOkWfYRCw', 'http://aepsustainability.com/performance/docs/2020AEPGRIReport.pdf']  # sample
```

However, ones that are working URLs, throw this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data'
```

I don't have the directory opened, nor files since I they're not downloaded.

I ran in **Terminal** without luck:

```
sh-4.2$ chmod 777 data
sh-4.2$ chmod 777 data/
sh-4.2$ chmod 777 data/gri
sh-4.2$ chmod 777 data/gri/
```

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import opendatasets as od
import urllib
import zipfile
import os

csr_df = pd.read_excel('data/Company Sustainability Reports.xlsx', index_col=None)
url_list = csr_df['Report PDF Address'].tolist()

for url in url_list:
    try:
        download = od.download(url, '/data/gri/')
        filename = url.rsplit('/', 1)[1]

        path_extract = 'data/gri/' + filename
        with zipfile.ZipFile('data/gri/' + filename + '.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(path_extract)

        os.remove(path_extract + 'readme.txt')

        filenames = os.listdir(path_extract)
        scans = []
        for f in filenames:
            with Image.open(path_extract + f) as img:
                matrix = np.array(img)
                scans.append(matrix)

        # shutil.rmtree(path_extract)
        os.remove(path_extract[:-1] + '.zip')

    except (urllib.error.URLError, IOError, RuntimeError) as e:
        print('Download PDFs', e)
```

**Output:**

```
Download PDFs list index out of range
Download PDFs list index out of range
Download PDFs list index out of range
Download PDFs list index out of range
Download PDFs <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'imagepool.1und1-drillisch.de'. (_ssl.c:1091)>
Download PDFs <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'imagepool.1und1-drillisch.de'. (_ssl.c:1091)>
Download PDFs list index out of range
Download PDFs [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data'
...
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`download` has a forward-slash `/` as first character of save directory (second parameter). I removed this:

```
download = od.download(url, 'data/gri/')
```

Output:

```
...
Downloading http://youxin.37.com/uploads/file/1556248045.pdf to data/gri/1556248045.pdf
450560it [00:02, 207848.59it/s]
...
```

Comment: Will accept answer in 2 days